# Dynamically filling a dropdown box in a web page using an Excel sheet with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet say A that contains a list from A1 to A75 that has to be dynamically replace the value in a webpage that contains a drop down list.

For each and every replacement value it needs to pull the report from the web page and save that to an Excel sheet B.

All of this function has to happen by clicking a form control button in Excel.

Please suggest & post the code if any.

---

I'm new to VBA and Excel; I’ve been instructed to get the values of currencies across the world with other currencies. This has to be done 365 days.

Although I’ve suggested to try with Macro in order to pull the data from webpage to excel, but after viewing the site i came to know that each and every currency has to be selected from the dropdown list and need to export those currencies to an excel file.

This becomes a hectic issue, so i thought of a solution and come up with an idea (I'm not sure whether this gonna work or not) and posted here to seek assistance for this issue.

//
Further assistance to the question, Excel file contains more than 75 currencies and those currencies need to be selected with the System date and need to select the Currency code starting from "AED" to "ZWD", for each entry need to export the file to excel. There is an option available for that in that webpage.
//

Hope this clarifies your requirement, for further assistance please let me know !

Best Regards,Pravin

Comment: Your question lacks enough detail to make any suggestions. What's stopping *you* from achieving your goal?

Comment: Please let me know if in case the above needs to be still clarified ! @TimWilliams

Comment: What web page are you working with?  Need a URL.

Comment: Its an official website, i'm not suppose to provide that, sorry. Probably you can have a look at [link] (oanda.com) Note : Oanda doesnt provide any special feature to export the file into excel.@TimWilliams

Comment: I'm just guessing looking at a different site. If you can't at least post the relevant HTML we can't offer anything specific.

Comment: I guess this is enough, [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwyKq2OBVvcFT3VGWUZvSXRiRE0/view?usp=sharing)
By looking at this might get you some idea how it looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's hard if you don't have good VBA and HTML knowledge.

in general you can do this by using a http request object instead of the IE automation. This is faster and from my point of view also easier:

```
Dim oRequest As Object
Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
oRequest.Open "GET", "http://www.cboden.de"
oRequest.Send
MsgBox oRequest.ResponseText
```

If you are behind a proxy you can use something like this:

```
Const HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY = 2
Dim oRequest As Object
Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
oRequest.setProxy HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY, "http://proxy.intern:8080"
oRequest.Open "GET", "http://www.cboden.de"
oRequest.Send
MsgBox oRequest.ResponseText
```

and if you want to use POST (instead of the GET method) to pass some values to the webserver, you can try this:

```
Dim oRequest As Object
Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
oRequest.Open "POST", "http://www.cboden.de/misc/posttest.php"
oRequest.SetRequestHeader "Content-Typ", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
oRequest.Send "var1=123&anothervar=test"
MsgBox oRequest.ResponseText
```

if you put it into a function then you can use it in you worksheet:

```
Function getCustomHyperlink(ByVal pURL As String) As String
    Dim oRequest As Object
    Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    oRequest.Open "GET", pURL
    oRequest.Send
    getCustomHyperlink = oRequest.ResponseText
End Function
```

within the worksheet you can then say for example:

```
=getCustomHyperlink("https://www.google.com/search?q=" & A1 )
```

if your search value is in A1

If you have to use the GET or the POST method depends on the website you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

## 1 In Excel IDE, add reference to "C:\Windows\System32\ieframe.dll".

(Press F11 excel to go to IDE) (Tools | Reference | Browse | locate the above file )

## 2 Create a module with following code and run it.  It will open the IE and go the yahoo site

```
Sub aa()
Dim aa As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
aa.Visible = True
aa.Navigate "http://www.yahoo.com.hk"
Stop
End Sub
```

## 3 Complete the above program by this idea:

- Excel program is emulating a user navigation to the required web page.
- The program waits the page is completely loaded.  Then read the page content by aa.document.
- Write the required data from aa.document into an excel worksheet.
- Repeat.